# How do I inspect a Singleton in the Flex Debugger?

Tags: apache-flex, singleton, debugging

I'm storing my model data in a Singleton called ModelLocator. This is pretty common...

Can I look at this data in the debugger?

[Edited - Title changed]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes.
you'd do something like the following.

```
var model : MySingleton = MySingleton.getInstance();
```

then stick a breakpoint at the above and you'll be able to see everything inside your model.